# Android Resource Linking Failed on Apk Build

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Goodday, I am getting this error when i decide to build my android app on Android Studio. Please how do i fix

> **C:\Users\HP-PC.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\dc1436142102318e0c7f87330e8cc57a\jetified-pinpad-1.0.1\res\values\values.xml:7:5-161: AAPT: error: resource attr/foreground (aka com.cptvstudio.tv:attr/foreground) not found.**
>
> **C:\Users\HP-PC.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\dc1436142102318e0c7f87330e8cc57a\jetified-pinpad-1.0.1\res\values\values.xml:7:5-161: AAPT: error: resource attr/foregroundGravity (aka com.cptvstudio.tv:attr/foregroundGravity) not found.**

I do not know where the error might be coming from. Below is my values.xml code if it might help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="pstck_pinpad_default_button_textcolor">#DFE1E2</color>
    <color name="pstck_pinpad_default_pin_indicator_empty_color">#E0E0E0</color>
    <color name="pstck_pinpad_default_pin_indicator_filled_color">#C4C4C4</color>
    <color name="pstck_pinpad_default_prompt_textcolor">#D0D0D0</color>
    <declare-styleable name="ForegroundView"><attr name="foreground"/><attr name="foregroundInsidePadding"/><attr name="foregroundGravity"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="PinPadView"><attr format="boolean" name="place_digits_randomly"/><attr format="boolean" name="auto_submit"/><attr format="boolean" name="vibrate_on_incomplete_submit"/><attr format="color" name="pin_indicator_filled_color"/><attr format="color" name="pin_indicator_empty_color"/><attr format="dimension" name="pin_indicator_size"/><attr format="dimension" name="pin_indicator_stroke_width"/><attr format="dimension" name="pin_indicator_spacing"/><attr format="integer" name="pin_length"/><attr format="string" name="prompt_text"/><attr format="color" name="prompt_textcolor"/><attr format="dimension" name="prompt_textsize"/><attr format="dimension" name="prompt_text_padding"/><attr format="dimension" name="prompt_text_paddingTop"/><attr format="dimension" name="prompt_text_paddingBottom"/><attr format="color" name="button_textcolor"/><attr format="dimension" name="button_numeric_textsize"/><attr format="dimension" name="button_alpha_textsize"/><attr format="string" name="button_text_numeric"/><attr format="string" name="button_text_alpha"/><attr format="reference" name="button_drawable"/><attr format="dimension" name="button_drawable_size"/></declare-styleable>
    <dimen name="pstck_pinpad__default_indicator_height">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pstck_pinpad__default_prompt_padding">24dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pstck_pinpad__default_prompt_paddingBottom">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pstck_pinpad__default_prompt_paddingTop">16dp</dimen>
    <string name="pstck_pinpad__app_name">pinpad</string>
    <string name="pstck_pinpad__num_0">0</string>
    <string name="pstck_pinpad__num_1">1</string>
    <string name="pstck_pinpad__num_2">2</string>
    <string name="pstck_pinpad__num_3">3</string>
    <string name="pstck_pinpad__num_4">4</string>
    <string name="pstck_pinpad__num_5">5</string>
    <string name="pstck_pinpad__num_6">6</string>
    <string name="pstck_pinpad__num_7">7</string>
    <string name="pstck_pinpad__num_8">8</string>
    <string name="pstck_pinpad__num_9">9</string>
    <style name="Widget"/>
    <style name="Widget.PinPad">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="button_textcolor">@color/pstck_pinpad_default_button_textcolor</item>
        <item name="prompt_textcolor">@color/pstck_pinpad_default_prompt_textcolor</item>
        <item name="pin_indicator_filled_color">@color/pstck_pinpad_default_pin_indicator_filled_color</item>
        <item name="pin_indicator_empty_color">@color/pstck_pinpad_default_pin_indicator_empty_color</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your attr file again `<attr name="foreground"/> and <attr name="foregroundGravity"/>` not defined in attr file